# Why can‘t updateSql be excuted in while-loop？

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis

When I have a select this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:XXXXX", "username", "psw");
            Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
            String selectSql="select h.id, h.user_id,h.start_time,h.end_time,h.start_date,h.end_date, a.time_zone from hos_driving_log h left join user_info ua on h.user_id= ua.user_id left JOIN account a on a.acct_id = ua.acct_id";

            ResultSet ress = stm.executeQuery(selectSql);
            while(ress.next()){
                int id = ress.getInt("id");
                String user_id = ress.getString("user_id");
                long start_time = ress.getLong("start_time");
                long end_time = ress.getLong("end_time");
                int start_date = ress.getInt("start_date");
                int end_date = ress.getInt("end_date");
                String time_zone = ress.getString("time_zone");
                System.out.println(id+" "+user_id+" "+start_time+" "+end_time+" "+start_date+" "+end_date+" "+time_zone);
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //Close the resources - Done automatically by try-with-resources
}
```

Output:

> 1 testuser 20151025021324 20151026024135 0 0 GMT-12:00
>   2 hostest 20151026024135 20151022080352 0 0 GMT-07:00
>   24 stress0101 20151208075641 20151208075717 0 0 null
>   88 123 c 20151224085208 20151224130803 0 0 null
>   89 123 c 20151224130916 20151224130922 0 0 null
>   90 123 c 20151224130917 20151224130923 0 0 null
>   91 123 c 20151224130918 20151224130924 0 0 null
>   92 123 c 20151224130919 20151224130925 0 0 null

But when I want to update in the loop:

```
try{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:XXXXX", "username", "psw");
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        String selectSql="select h.id, h.user_id,h.start_time,h.end_time,h.start_date,h.end_date, a.time_zone from hos_driving_log h left join user_info ua on h.user_id= ua.user_id left JOIN account a on a.acct_id = ua.acct_id";

        ResultSet ress = stm.executeQuery(selectSql);
        while(ress.next()){
            int id = ress.getInt("id");
            String user_id = ress.getString("user_id");
            long start_time = ress.getLong("start_time");
            long end_time = ress.getLong("end_time");
            int start_date = ress.getInt("start_date");
            int end_date = ress.getInt("end_date");
            String time_zone = ress.getString("time_zone");
            System.out.println(id+" "+user_id+" "+start_time+" "+end_time+" "+start_date+" "+end_date+" "+time_zone);
            start_date = getDrivingLogShortTypeDate(start_time, time_zone);
            end_date = getDrivingLogShortTypeDate(end_time, time_zone);
            String updateSql = "update hos_driving_log set start_date = "+ start_date+",end_date = "+end_date+" where id="+id;
            int i = stm.executeUpdate(updateSql);
            System.out.println(updateSql);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
//Close the resources - Done automatically by try-with-resources
```

... it only does one update:

> 45 co2-stress0096 20151222090816 20151222091436 20151222 20151222 GMT+08:00
>   update hos_driving_log set start_date = 20151222,end_date = 20151222 where id=45

Why is it stopping after one update? How can I get all of the rows to be updated?

Comment: Please put _some_ effort into formatting your post. The help center can help you if you don't know how to use the UI.

Comment: It seems to be completely different data, since 45 isn't in the first output. Has the data changed? Or are you connecting to a different database or schema?

Comment: @JOLee you mean that the print statement prints only one time, after update statements are added? Did you check the database?

Comment: Why all the downvotes on this question?  It was a fair question and all the information needed to answer it was provided.

Comment: @JOLee Although your comments in the code says to use try with resources, you haven't. Better use them or close the resources with a finally block.

Comment: @224 database only change one row, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

You are re-executing the statement object `stm` from which your result set was generated.  You need to use a separate statement object for the update.

Also, do not build your SQL update statements by concatenating literals into the SQL.  Use bind variables and your users and DBAs will all thank you.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Comment: Also, do not build your SQL update statements by concatenating literals into the SQL. Use bind variables and your users and DBAs will all thank you.-------------------what it is meaning?

Comment: Basically, you reuse the same SQL for every update.  If you do 1000 updates, it's the difference between parsing 1000 times and caching 1000 statements vs. parsing and caching only one statement.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html